# How to add row element from specific column and find out percentage value of such 2 of them?

Tags: linux, shell

When I do df  ,I get folowing results.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1529860        4   1529856   1% /dev
tmpfs             308116      960    307156   1% /run
/dev/sda1       47929224 40768468   4703004  90% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1540572       76   1540496   1% /run/shm
none              102400       44    102356   1% /run/user
Shared         168479740 78002196  90477544  47% /media/sf_Shared
/dev/sr0           83904    83904         0 100% /media/amitk/VBox_GAs_6.0.41
```

Here I am taking "**1K-blocks**" column values of "**sda1**" and "**Shared**" then add them 47929224 + 168479740 =216408964 .Also, I want **used space** of the respective memory blocks i.e.for Sda1 =40768468 and Shared = 78002196 so 40768468+78002196 =118770664. I want to do (118770664 *100)/ 216408964 =54.88 and store the result in EmmcSpace.txt file.

But I am stucked with this calculation part.I don't want "use%" column for some reason. So how do I move ahead so that finally in the EmmcSpace.txt file there should only percentage value i.e. 54.88 or 54 and nothing else

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(void)
    {   
        system("df |grep sda1 |awk -F ' ' '{print $2, $3}' >EmmcSpace.txt");
        system("df |grep Shared |awk -F ' ' '{print $2, $3}' >>EmmcSpace.txt");
        
        system("awk '{total1 = total1 + $1}END{print total1}' EmmcSpace.txt >>EmmcSpace.txt");
        system("awk '{total2 = total2 + $2}END{print total2}' EmmcSpace.txt >>EmmcSpace.txt");
        
        //system("awk '{printf  (($total2 *100) / ($total1))}' EmmcSpace.txt");
        //system("total='expr $total1 \* 100' '{print total}'");
        //system("total=`expr $total1 \* 100` ");
        //system("total=`expr $total / total2`");
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: So you're asking about awk scripts and not about C?

Comment: If your C program has nothing but calls to `system()`, you shouldn't be using C for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On surface, the OP want to retrieve total blocks on two local file system (sda1 and shared), and report the % usage of the combined. Most modern versions of 'df' have a '--total' which performs exactly that

```
df --total / /media/sf_Shared
```